# keep name domain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem. I have a hosting with piensasolutions and two domains. The first domain controls the hosting and the second use a domain parking.

Let `a.com` be the first domain and `b.com` be the second domain.

My domain parking for `b.com` allows me to redirect from `b.com` to `a.com/folder`, (where folder contains the web page where I want to point with `b.com`).

The problem is that I want to show `b.com` URL instead of `a.com/folder` URL, I am not sure if the problem is from piensasolutions because I tried several .htaccess files but I was not able to change the URL of the web browser. This was my last test which supposes to keep the original URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?a.com/folder/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a.com/folder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?b.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b.com/$1 [L]
```

For additional information, I put the .htaccess file inside the `a.com/folder`. I am not sure about the redirection of piensasolutions.

If your are able to help me, I will be really grateful, and also if you have dedicated a couple of minutes even if you have not find the anwser.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is usig sites-avaiable.
First of all,

```
$ vi /etc/host
```

and copy the next line:

```
127.0.0.1   a
127.0.0.1   b
```

Then, create two new sites:

```
$ touch /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/a
$ touch /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/b
```

and edit them

```
$ vi /etc/apache2/sites-avaiables/a


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName a
DocumentRoot /your_path_to_server/a/folder
    <Directory /your_path_to_server/a/folder/>
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All          
                    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
$ vi /etc/apache2/sites-avaiables/b


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName b
DocumentRoot /your_path_to_server/b
    <Directory /your_path_to_server/b/>
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All          
                    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and that's all. This should work.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I have not access to the server, I am only able to modify the host files